# The imageView can not connect to the header file for IBOulet in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iboutlet

I create a `xib` file from `New file -> iOS -> User Interface -> View` , and add a `Collection View Cell`.

I create a `header and .m file` from `New file -> iOS -> Cocoa Touch -> Objective-C class`. and set the `UICollectionViewCell` to `Subclass`.

I want to connect the `imageView` and `label` to `header file` for `IBOutlet` , but it has no any behavior.

Like the following picture.

[image]

Why this condition happened ? Did I missing something ?

Comment: select the ViewController and specify the custom class in order to connect the related outlet view

Comment: @staticVoidMan Excuse me , you mean add the ViewController in xib file ?

Comment: @Martin I added a picture in my answer to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to select the View and add the custom class like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks , it is work. And sorry about the stupid question for new to IOS.